# .htaccess Issue on Mac

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I am trying to use the following .htaccess rewrite rules but it just does not work for some reason.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*) /index.php?_controller=$1&_action=$2$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)(.*) /index.php?_controller=$1$2 [QSA,L]
```

I would like a url like this:

```
http://name.local/someFolder/?_controller=aController&_action=anAction
```

To be converted to:

```
http://name.local/someFolder/aController/anAction
```

I am not sure why my rewrite rules wont work like I want them to, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: These rules do not make much sense: matching `([^/]+)(.*)` and then replacing by `$1$2` ?? It's the same as `(.+)` and `$1`. As I understand you want to place such rewrite rule in `/somefolder/.htaccess` -- am I correct? (I need to know this in order to write a rule without a need of modifying it later).

Comment: @LazyOne yes my .htaccess is in the /someFolder/ which is the webroot for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Such rewrite can be done like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?_controller=$1&_action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

It will rewrite (internal redirect) request for `/first/second` to `/index.php?_controller=first&_action=second`.

It will only work if you requesting non-existing resource. So, if you have such folder `/first/second`, then no rewrite will happen.

---

If you change pattern from `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` to `^([^/]+)/([^/]*)$`, then it will also be applicable for this rewrite: `/first/` to `/index.php?_controller=first&_action=` (notice that trailing slash is required here).

---

If you change pattern from `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` to `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$`, then both `/first/second` and `/first/second/` (one with trailing slash) will trigger the rule.

---

If you change pattern from `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` to `^([^/]+)(/([^/]*))?$`, then this single rewrite rule will match `/first/second` as well as `/first/` as well as `/first` (obviously, if 2nd segment is not present, then action parameter `_action=` will be empty).

It is also possible to make trailing slash with 2 segments optional (i.e. `/first/second` and `/first/second/` will be treated as the same (from rewriting point of view). For that -- change pattern to `^([^/]+)(/([^/]*))?/?$`.